# Is it possible to connect two AUI transceivers?

Tags: ethernet

I have a system which has a proprietary internal network and provides an external [AUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_Unit_Interface). I cannot find a switch or hub with AUI port. Are whose hubs/switches with AUI port still around?

In general a [MAU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Attachment_Unit) is used to convert from [MDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium-dependent_interface) to [AUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attachment_Unit_Interface). Can I connect two MAU on the AUI side? With a cross-over AUI cable?

I am wondering if this chain could work:

|  | < not allowed to change |  | free to find solution > |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| internal network xyz | xyz MAU |  | custom cable | MAU RJ45 | RJ45 switch |

The `custom cable` would need

- connect RX&TX crossed (DO-A to DI-A, DO-B to DI-B)
- connect the collision detection lines (CI-B to VC)
- 12V & 0V supply for both transceivers (12V to VP, 0V to VC)

Answer (score 2):

For such an ancient AUI port you'll need an MAU or transceiver - the MAU effectively converts the AUI to an MDI suitable for your network (works with any port backward compatible with 10BASE-T). I'm not sure if they can still be bought new but you can get them used.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Attachment_Unit

Comment: I have an existing equipment with provides my an AUI interface. Equipment internally does 10BASE over coax). Can I connect such a MAU directly to that AUI interface?

Comment: @FlorianZidar I'm not sure what you're asking - a MAU has a male connector and directly connects to a female AUI port (or even with an extension cable). AUI ports are not intended to be connected using a custom, crossover cable, although that *might* be possible. If I don't understand you correctly, please edit your answer for details about what you mean by "existing equipment" and "internal network", perhaps a photo.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Zac's answer, you can still get transceivers, e.g. Black Box sells a 10BaseT to AUI transceiver.

Another option to look for used would be an old 3Com combo hub: OfficeConnect Hub TP4Combo model 3C16703 - these had thinwire, AUI, and 10BaseT ports.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the combo hub. I guess this should work, as the existing AUI tranceiver needs to be powered from our side. Again many thanks.

Comment: I would like to point out, that even with that modelnumber it is hard to find one that actually supports AUI.